# Could not find Microsoft Silverlight SDK v3.0

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

Hi i am trying to make a simple Microsoft Silverlight application.I have Visual Studio 2010 installed on my computer along with Silverlight 3.0 sdk. But while running the project it gives an error. "Could not find Microsoft Silverlight SDK v3.0. Plase make sure that the correct version of the Microsoft Silverlight SDK has been installed."
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, Install the [Microsoft Silverlight SDK v4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7335) and try again.